# Reference-Request: Symmetric Product Schemes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Is there a good reference for the theory of symmetric product schemes? (I only need a few basic things, the construction, etc.)

Googling it turned up a lot of papers which use it as if it's common knowledge, so I suspect there should be a reference somewhere, but I can't find any.

Comment: Do you know how to construct products of schemes? Do you know how to quotient schemes by the action of a finite group?

Comment: I didn't know that you could quotient schemes by the action of a finite group. How would you do that?

Comment: If $R$ is a commutative ring, then an action of $G$ on $\text{Spec } R$ by scheme automorphisms is equivalent to an action of $G$ on $R$ by ring automorphisms, and $\text{Spec } R^G$ is a sensible model of the quotient scheme (where $R^G$ denotes the invariant subring of $R$). The inclusion $R^G \to R$ dualizes to the quotient map $\text{Spec } R \to \text{Spec } R^G$. To extend this to schemes it suffices to find a covering by $G$-invariant affine opens; unfortunately I am not sure if this is always possible...

Comment: Hmm, the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1558/quotients-of-schemes-by-free-group-actions seem to suggest that it's not always possible to quotient by a finite group...

Comment: Yes, okay, the issue is that orbits may not be contained in affine opens. For any scheme $S$ such that a finite subset of $S$ is contained in an affine open this is not a problem for the action of the symmetric group on $S \times S \times ... \times S$.

Comment: Oops, I missed an answer to that question further down, by David Speyer, which states that a quotient always exists if the scheme is quasi-projective, which suffices for my purposes.

The argument requires Hilbert schemes though, and I'm not familiar with their machinery; My question is mainly motivated by Fulton's intersection theory, which doesn't mention Hilbert schemes (judging by the index). I was hoping that symmetric product schemes would be a simpler example.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a reference addressing exactly your question, so I'll just try my best to answer your question using more general knowledge and providing a number of references.

- If we have a finite group $G$ acting on a finitely generated algebra $A$ over a field $k$, we know by the Artin-Tate lemma that $A^G$ is also noetherian (it is a finitely generated algebra over $k$ in case $A$ is).  You can find this e.g. in Atiyah & Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra.  The idea is that $A$ is an $A^G$-module of finite type.  It is easy to see that $K^G$ is the quotient field of $A^G$, in the case where $A$ is a domain.
- For actions of finite groups on schemes: when we have a scheme $S$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $X$, one may reduce with some generality to the affine case, solved above.  Indeed, this is the case for $X$ quasiprojective scheme over a ring $A$ (we will take $A$ to be Noetherian).  I know that this result is due to Michael Artin, but I saw it in James Milne's Etale Cohomology book.

  I would say that a good reference in general is Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory.

IMPORTANT: The condition that is required to ensure the reduction to the affine case is the following.  If any $G$-orbit admits an affine open set containing it, then we may construct $X/G$ by reduction to the affine case.  If $X$ is quasiprojective over an affine ring, this is the case for any finite set of points.

- It is easy to see that, if $X$ is normal, so is $X/G$ provided $X$ is quasiprojective over a field or so (i.e. provided we fall under the above hypotheses).
- In the case of a smooth curve $C$, you may consider the symmetric product $S^d(C).$  This is smooth, and the proof is done via local coordinates, as follows.

1) In the case where $C={\mathbb A}^1$, we are still in the affine case.  We know by the theorem on elementary symmetric polynomials (Waring) that (here $X=(X_i)_{i\leq n}$)

$$k[X]^{S_n}=k[s_1, \cdots , s_n],$$

where $s_i$ are defined by 
$$T^n-s_1T^{n-1} + \cdots +(-1)^ns_n= \prod (T-X_i).$$

2) In the case of a smooth curve $C$, consider a point  $\sum n_i P_i$, where $P_i \in C$ and $\sum n_i=d.$  Without much effort (but by proceeding carefully) one may reduce to the above by choosing local coordinates and considering the decomposition group of a point of $C^d$ above our chosen point in $S^dC$.

- If $X$ is a smooth projective surface, then the desingularisation of $S^dX$ (which is always non-smooth for $\dim X\geq 2$ as the branch locus is a union of diagonals which has codimension $\leq 2$) has a correspondence with the Hilbert scheme of zero-dimensional subschemes of $X$ of length $d$.  The standard reference is H. Nakajima's book:

http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Lectures_on_Hilbert_Schemes_of_Points_on.html?id=pjjgNhDVgcgC&redir_esc=y

- I remember that I.G. Macdonald has a book on symmetric functions, which perhaps is of some use to you, though it won't be the answer you seek, as your question stands.
- There is a paper by E. Freitag on J. Crelle on actions of finite groups on varieties (it contains some results on numerical invariants in the case of complex smooth projective varieties).

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/243110046_Die_Struktur_der_Funktionenkrper_zu_hyperabelschen_Gruppen._II

Finally, maybe you have heard of the Molien series (related to finite group actions on projective schemes over a field).