# Symmetric Product of a Projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Following the question,

Theon Alexander (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165460/theon-alexander), Reference-Request: Symmetric Product Schemes, URL (version: 2014-08-10): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893383

Suppose $X$ is a projective scheme over a field $k$ of $\text{char}=0$, (or more generally over a scheme $S$), then the symmetric product is defined by 
\begin{equation}
\text{Sym}^n(X)=X \times \cdots \times X/S_n
\end{equation}
where $S_n$ is the symmetric group. I have two questions,

First, how could we give $S_n$ a group scheme structure and let it act on $X \times \cdots \times X$ in the usual sense!

Second, generally the quotient always exist (assuming we have defined the action properly) since $S_n$ is finite hence reductive from Mumford's GIT, but we need to keep only the semi-stable part! But I kind of feel that since the action is so nice, the whole space $X \times \cdots \times X$ is semi-stable, is this true?

Comment: $S_n$ is a discrete group, you can view it as a zero-dimensional, reduced scheme if you really insist!

Comment: The question in your edit is sufficiently disjoint from the rest that you should really ask it separately.

Comment: For a finite group acting on an affine scheme, the quotient exists by taking ring of invariants. For a projective scheme with a finite group action, any orbit is a finite set and thus contained in an affine open set and then it is contained in an invariant affine open set.. Now, take quotients and patch.