# How to show $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From the question

Theon Alexander (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165460/theon-alexander), Reference-Request: Symmetric Product Schemes, URL (version: 2014-08-10): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893383

we know that 
\begin{equation}
\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{A}^1):=\mathbb{A}^1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{A}^1/S_n \cong \mathbb{A}^n
\end{equation}
where the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the $\mathbb{A}^1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{A}^1$ in the usual sense. But how to show $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{P}^n$?

Since we know that $\mathbb{P}^1$ is covered by two affine opens $\text{Spec}~k[x]$ and $\text{Spec}~k[t]$ via the gluing $x=1/t$, then I could see there are two affine opens of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^1)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\text{Sym}^n(\text{Spec}~k[x]) \cong \mathbb{A}^n,~~\text{Sym}^n(\text{Spec}~k[t]) \cong \mathbb{A}^n
\end{equation}
But how to find other affine opens and glue them together to $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Why do you assume these cover projective space? Do these two open sets cover product of $\mathbb{P}^1$? Try for $n=2$.

Comment: At least set-wise you can see this as follows: $n$ unordered points in $\mathbb P^1$ determine up to scalar a unique polynomial (the polynomial with those points as zeroes) in $\Gamma(\mathbb P^1, \mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1}(n))$. This vector space has dimension $n+1$, so its projectivisation is $\mathbb P^n$.